# Using C# code behind to check if the URL contains a key in order to change the page header depending on what the key is

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, key

I can get to one of my pages from different places in the site. Depending on where you're coming from, the URL might have a key in it. So for example, clicking on button 1 on page1.aspx will lead you to page3.aspx. Clicking on button 2 on page2.aspx will also lead to page3.aspx but the final url after the page loads will be page3.aspx?key=test whereas when you're clicking button 1 on page1.aspx, the url is simply page3.aspx.

I want to use code behind to change the header on page3.aspx. If the url on page3.aspx contains a key, I want the header to say "This header modified due to key." If it doesn't contain a key, I want it to remain the default. The default is currently text like "Default header."

So far, I've added code that appends a key to the button href attribute. Page 1's button leads to page3.aspx and page 2's button leads to page3.aspx?key=test, and both pages load. But for some reason, my code to change the header is not working. Here is what I have inside Page_Load:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    if(Request.UrlReferrer != null && (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower().Contains("key=test")))
    {
        PageHeader = "This header modified due to key.";
    }
}
```

That didn't work so I tried removing it from the !isPostBack block and just putting it right at the beginning of the Page_Load method. I also tried doing Contains("?key=ggg") instead but that was no different. I would appreciate any nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Apologies, I edited that. Should have been if(!IsPostBack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Request.QueryString` collection for it:

```
if(Request.QueryString["key"] != null)
  // do something here
```

or:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["key"])
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["key"])` since it's a string?

Comment: I tried both of those and neither worked. I can confirm that my url does in fact have the key in it. So for some reason, the change is just not taking place.

Comment: I tried it again, after debugging the order of my if statements, and both solutions work. Thanks for your help. Lesson learned - next time, I'll use the debugger before asking a question, rather than just typing away and compiling.

Comment: @mason added that as well